# How to change a character's pose without stretching any body parts?

Tags: animation, rigging, pose-mode

I want to force [rain v2](https://cloud.blender.org/p/characters/5f04a68bb5f1a2612f7b29da) to not stretch. How can I achieve that?
In the screenshot you can see, that I turned off stretching. But whenever I want to change the pose of rain v2 some body part stretches.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select an IK target (can be moved without stretch), while you appeared to select an FK target (should only be Rotated, can stretch the character if Moved).  You can disable FK or Stretch Layers to avoid these when doing IK manipulation.

[image]